# PnP Modern Search. Filter Current user

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I would like to be able to display list results to users that only contain their name.
I have 2 possible ways I think this can be done, but not sure how.

In the **Query template** section, I have `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/site/Lists/listname/`.

But I cant use the URL that has a custom user view. Is this possible? e.g. `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/site/Lists/listname/Current-User.aspx`

OR my second choice is using the **Refinement filters**. I have tried using **Title:equals(userName)**. But does not work. I do have the Title field filled out with the username.

Is it even possible to filter results based on who's logged in?
Thanks

Comment: Based on which column you want to filter? created by, modified by or any other custom user column? can you share more detail about your list?

Comment: More infomation:

I have a sharepoint list that contains an entry for every user in the company. I have the username being filled in Title Field. 

In the PnP sharepoint webpark i only want to display list infomation to the current user that has thier name in it. I don't want other users seeing eachothers fields.

Comment: You can get display name of current user using these tokens: `{User}` or `{User.Name}`. Check more information & properties at: https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/tokens/#user-tokens. You can use this to match it with your Title column in the list.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get display name of currently logged in user using either of below tokens:

1. `{User}` or
2. `{User.Name}`.

You can also get the Email and other properties from user profile.

Check more information & available properties at: [User Tokens](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/tokens/#user-tokens).

You can use these tokens to match it with your Title column in the SharePoint list.